# Imagen de fondo en Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic, login, programación-móvil

Estoy intentando poner una  imagen de fondo para un login, el código es el siguiente:

home page:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

variable.scss
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me lanza lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Parece que el compilador no puede vincular la ruta. 
Prueba con mover la imagen a **src/assets/** y referenciarla con `url('assets/fondo.jpg')`